# Installing MvvmCross.Core in Xamarin.iOS Unified API

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I created a Unified API project, and installed [combined PCL profile + NuGet 2.8.3 alpha installer](http://xvs.xamarin.com/Xamarin.iOS.PortableNuGet.msi) according to [this](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/24976/xamarin-ios-mvvmcross).

So, now my profile 78 now recognizes the Xamarin.iOS Unified project. But when, I'm trying to add the MvvmCross package in the project it is installing the MvvmCross.Core framework instead of the MvvmCross.Touch framework.

I also read [here](http://slodge.blogspot.com.br/) that the unified iOS mvvmcross touch is included in 3.2.2 beta1. So, in Package Manager Console I'm checking Include pre-release and installing the 3.2.2 beta1 but it still downloading the MvvmCross.Core framework.

Anyone knows what can be happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MvvmCross 3.2.2-beta1 does not contain any assemblies that explicitly target the new Xamarin.iOS Unified target framework.

In order for MvvmCross to explicitly target Xamarin.iOS it would need a corresponding lib directory in its NuGet package. Looking at MvvmCross.HotTuna.CrossCore 3.2.2-beta1 on NuGet, for example, it has the following lib directories:

- MonoAndroid
- MonoTouch
- net45
- netcore45
- portable-win+net45+wp8+win8+wpa81+MonoTouch+MonoAndroid
- portable-win81+wpa81
- win81
- wp8
- wpa81

This is missing a Xamarin.iOS10 directory and associated assemblies that target Xamarin.iOS Unified.

So the only assemblies that could possibly be used in a Xamarin.iOS Unified project are the PCL assemblies from the MvvmCross NuGet packages.

Looking at the [pull request](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/pull/813) that is linked to by the blog post announcing support for Xamarin.iOS Unified they seem to have put support for Xamarin.iOS Unified into version 3.5 and not 3.2.2.

Comment: Also see "The awesome first Alpha of Unified API and Woah Fragments v3.5 is on OneDrive" - https://twitter.com/MvvmCross/status/533363412936708097